# Can I get roll-up summary field without a master-detail relationship

Tags: master-detail, roll-up-summary

We are trying to move to the Standard Order Object from a Custom object we used to track Orders (`Orders1`) - Since `Orders1` was a custom object I was able to create a Master-Detail relationship with Accounts and subsequently a Roll-up Summary field to calculate the earliest Order date (MIN of First Order Date) from multiple orders.

Being that the Order object is a Standard object I am not able to create a Master-Detail relationship with Accounts (another Standard  object) and hence cannot create a Roll-Up Summary field to track.

Any non-coding related suggestions or work-around would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Is this one time migration from Order1 to Standard Order? 2. Is there a chance to update order date of any orders? Please let me know, as I am investigating on the non-coding workaround (it may sound silly)

Comment: Hi Santanu,  I am migrating from a custom Order object to the standard Order object and if I get your question correctly... Yes as an Admin you can change the Order Date to the original date from the old object with a tool like Apex DataLoader.  I believe the date in the standard Order object is "EffectiveDate" (versus CreatedDate, which you cannot change.  LEt me know if this was helpful.

Comment: If it is one time migration from Order1 to Standard Order, then you can setup a logic at process builder to calculate the min(Orderdate) and post that on Account

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  Yes I am doing a one time migration from old to new, but subsequent new orders need to also be taken into account as part of the roll-up summary.  Hence the suggestion of the "Declarative-Lookup-Rollup-Summaries" app accomplished exactly what I was looking for.  Presumably I could set this up in Process Builder as you suggest, but why do that if an app already exists!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, quite simply, you should install [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). Then you can create a `Lookup Rollup Summary` to implement this functionality.

Comment: Wow I wish I had heard of this a long time ago... would have saved me tons of time - Thanks!